# C++ use inner enum for class template

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates

```
template <Type T>
class Socket {
public:
    enum class Type {
        TCP,
        UDP
    };
    ...
}
```

How I can use enum `Type` for class template? I want to use it as `Socket::Type::UDP` and etc.
I try declare `enum class Socket::Type` before `Socket` but it doesn't work.

Comment: How would you use it? `Socket<Socket<???>::Type::TCP>`

Comment: I want to use it as `Socket::Type::TCP`

Comment: It is not possible. A template is only a template until you provide the parameters.

Comment: If it's about keeping it in something, consider a namespace.

Comment: BTW why is your socket a template? Aren't sockets just binary data streams?

Comment: @PasserBy, It's templated on protocol, not data type.

Comment: @chris Oh, I'm blind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `Socket<...>` has a different `Type` enum. Apart from the separate enum types, one reason it isn't possible to use `Socket::Type` is that a specialization of `Socket` could not even include the enum, or make `Type` something other than an enum.

You have two main options:

1. Use a separate class/namespace named closely:

   ```
   class Sockets {
   public:
       enum class Type { ... };
   };

   template<Sockets::Type T>
   class Socket { ... };

   Socket<Sockets::Type::TCP> s;
   ```
2. Use a separate enum type:

   ```
   enum class SocketType { ... };

   template<SocketType T>
   class Socket { ... };

   Socket<SocketType::TCP> s;
   ```

Alternatively, don't template `Socket`. You'll surely end up with a bunch of `if (T == TCP) { ... } else { ... }`. It would likely be better to cleanly separate the common parts and use two different implementations for TCP and UDP.